# __getattr__ going recursive in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the declared a class in following way

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, list_1, list_2):
        self.list1 = list_1
        self.list2 = list_2

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.list1: return "It is in list 1"
        elif item in self.list2: return "It is in list 2"
        else: return "It is in neither list 1 nor list 2"
```

Here when I am adding `__setattr__` `self.list`1 goes recursive, since `__getattr__` get called after every `self.list1` and this recursion is unstoppable. Can you please help me out with it. I need to implement like this.

Thanks

Comment: You mention `__setattr__` but it is not in your code.  Please explain how you are using `__setattr__`, if you are.

Comment: Try adding something like: `if item in ["list1","list2"]: return self.__dict__[item]` at the start of `__getattr__()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, this is a totally bizarre usage of `__getattr__`, but I'll assume that you know that.

Basically, the problem is that `__setattr__` is always called every time you do something like `self.foo = bar`, so if you use that within `__setattr__` you'll end up with the recursion that you got.  What you need to do is insert the value that you're trying to set directly into `__dict__` `self.__dict__['foo'] = bar`.

If you're using new style classes (i.e. `A` is a descendant of `object`), then you could also do `super(A, self).__setattr__(item, value)` or even just `object.__setattr__(self, item, value)`